# Display posts by tag

Tags: wp-query, tags

I'm trying to display a list of posts by tag within a post. I've cobbled together the following code which I wanted to use in a shortcode, but I'm getting nothing displayed…

```
$args = array(
'tag' => 'my-tag'
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        $query->get_template_part( 'entry-summary' );
    }
}
get_template_part( 'nav', 'below' );
```

I've tried using this within the loop using a short code and after the loop to test without success. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious!

Comment: Doesn't seem to make any difference I'm afraid.

Comment: See the updated answer. And please remember to add `wp_reset_postdata();` afterwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try without `$query->` in front of `get_template_part()` ?

Comment: That just causes the server and the browser to go into some sort of meltdown!

Comment: @Badger check, I have updated the answer to be correct. It should work now

Comment: I have edited the wrong part out of the answer. The part that is staying should be the correct part. If anyone has an issue with this, feel free to roll back my changes ;-)

Comment: Thanks @PieterGoosen for your correction and I'm glad it works now ^^